# Excel: Get Last characters from parent folder to sub folder

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need your help very badly. I need to get last characters from Folder Name and Sub Folder(if any). To make my point clearly I am giving an example below.

Eg 1:

`E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_**1**\SubFolder**1**\Sub_Folder**2**\SubFolder**3**\SubFolder**4**\file.txt`

Need to get string "**11234**".

Eg2:

`E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_**1**\SubFolder**2**\Sub_Folder**5**\SubFolder**6**\SubFolder**9**\file.txt`

Need to get string "**12569**".

I Have tried below code to get last character.

```
=FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))/LEN("\")))
```

But I need to search in sub folders(if any) too.

Really appreciate if you guys can provide any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the answer to your original post, e.g. corresponding to the sample E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_1\SubFolder1\Sub_Folder2\SubFolder3\SubFolder4\file.txt (no ** stuff). Best regards,

Comment: What was the problem with the previous answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to you problem is to create UDF VBA as shown below:

1). Add Module to you Excel Workbook (Module1 by default) and place a User Defined Function (UDF) in that module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetLastChars(InputText As Range) As String
    Dim tmp As String, ret As String
    'skip E:\User\Images\ as per your example
    tmp = Replace(InputText.Value, "E:\User\Images\", "")
    'loop through the rest of subfolders
    Do While (InStr(tmp, "\")) > 0
        'adding the last letters to return var
        ret = ret & Mid(tmp, InStr(tmp, "\") - 1, 1)
        'progressing to the next subfolder
        tmp = Mid(tmp, InStr(tmp, "\") + 1)
    Loop
    'concatenated last letters of subfolders
    GetLastChars = ret
End Function
```

2) Assuming that as per you example the original data (path) is inserted in Cell "A1", enter in Cell "B1" the formula `=GetLastChars(A1)`; correspondingly, in Cell "B2" enter the Formula: `=GetLastChars(B1)`

Corresponding to your sample: `E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_1\SubFolder1\Sub_Folder2\SubFolder3\SubFolder4\file.txt` the return value is 11234.

This UDF will work on any number of sub-folders (skipping the root part `E:\User\Images` as per your sample).

For example: having the path entered as `E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_1\SubFolder1\Sub_Folder2\SubFolder3\SubFolder4\SubFolder5\SubFolder6\SubFolder7\file.txt` the formula returns **11234567**.

For path string like: E:\User\Images\Main_Folder_1\SubFolder1\Sub_Folder2\SubFolder3\SubFolder4\SubFolder5\SubFolder6\SubFolder7\SubFolder8\SubFolder9\SubFolder0\file.txt it returns **11234567890**, and so on.

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Worked like charm.. Need little more help.
In some folders, I have more than 9 sub folder, in this case it returns only last character. Please help. Awaiting your reply.

Comment: Good news. Please see my extended answer (the formula actually works on any number of sub-folders - see example). Best regards,

Comment: Instead of removing one character at the end, we can search for space from ending and get character after space. I think this should work.

Comment: Well, you can modify the formula up to your preference. Currently, it's been designed to fit your original specs. Frankly, I don't quite understand what space you are talking about (which line of code, or which sample string? I do not see any spaces...). Anyway, if you have more questions I would recommend to post it separately. Kind regards,

Comment: @Rahul: in case you are satisfied with the answer, would you please mark it accepted? Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

If your source data is as you show it; always starting with E:\User\Images, and **IF** that last character will always be a **single digit**, and **IF** there will always be **5** folders/subfolders,  you could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"E:\User\Images\",""),"\",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))-1)*99+1,99)),1)*10^{4;3;2;1;0})
```

Otherwise I would suggest this User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function GetLastFolderChar(S As String) As String
    Dim T() As String, U As String
    Dim I As Long
S = Replace(S, "E:\User\Images\", "")
T = Split(S, "\")

For I = LBound(T) To UBound(T) - 1
    U = U & Right(T(I), 1)
Next I

GetLastFolderChar = U

End Function
```

Comment: last character is not a single digit always and it can many sub folders.

Comment: @Rahul Then I would recommend the UDF I provided.